# Angular 5 - Change Chevron up and down on Column header click

Tags: javascript, angular5, font-awesome

I need to add font-awesome chevron icons to a table column headers to sort the data. While I am able to accomplish sorting functionality, I am unable to have the chevorn icons change to up/down properly in the event of click. Initially, these icons need to be displayed on all column headers and when we click on a particular header, that icon only need to be changed to up/down. So far, I have tried below code and is affecting all columns.

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headerClass" *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders" (click)="sortColumn(header)">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>{{header}}</td>
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" *ngIf="sortDirection === 'asc' && sortBy === header" ></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" *ngIf="sortDirection === 'desc' && sortBy === header"></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

**TypeScript**

```
sortBy: string = '';
sortDirection: string = 'desc';

sortColumn(headerName: string) {
    if (this.sortBy === headerName) {
      this.sortDirection = this.sortDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    }
    this.sortBy = headerName;
}
```

**Edit** - I am hitting back-end service to retrieve new data everytime i hit sort icons.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your tableHeaders objects to have 2 attribute like:

```
header = {
  name : something,
  direction : none ,
};
```

Then use :

```
 <th class="headerClass" *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders" (click)="sortColumn(header)">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{header.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <i class="fa fa-default-icon-you-want-for-table-headers" *ngIf="header.direction === 'none'"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" *ngIf="header.direction === 'asc'&& sortBy === header.name" ></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" *ngIf="header.direction === 'desc'&& sortBy === header.name"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
 </th>
```

And your function will be like :

```
sortColumn(header: any) {
if (this.sortBy === header.name) {
  header.direction= header.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
}

this.sortBy = header.name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working on the initial click, however, as soon as i hit another column header to sort, then the earlier column headers chevron-down icon is disappearing (I am hitting backend to get latest on sort icon hit which rewrites the headers_. I have used chevron-down as my default icon. that's the only change i made

Comment: better soloution will be that you check header.direction for each header ,each time you get sortBy from server and change it to default if it is not equal to what you want , do like :
getSortBy(){
 this.whateverserviceyouuse.getSortBy()
.subscribe((data)=>{
this.sortBy = data ; 
for(let headers of tableHeaders)
if(data === header.name){
header.direction= header.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
}
else{ 
 header.direction= none ;
}
)